# Asking for/providing links to (probably) illegal ebooks

Tags: discussion, copyright

In the last days I encountered at least two questions (that I still recall) in which people were asking for/providing links to complete ebooks.

While I know that some authors choose to publish their book freely available online, I am pretty sure that this is not the case here.

Is there a policy established regarding those posts?

Points in case:

[book recommendation on functional analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122953/book-recommendation-on-functional-analysis) (see the comment to one of the answers),

[Have a question about $L^p$ multiplier.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121938/have-a-question-about-lp-multiplier) (again, see the comments).

Comment: Somewhat related: [Requests for electronic versions of books](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005/requests-for-electronic-versions-of-books), [To what extent should copyrighted material be made available on math.se?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/529/to-what-extent-should-copyrighted-material-be-made-available-on-math-se) and several other discussions. (You can find some of them in the tag [meta-tag:copyright] and among the questions linked to the two I have mentioned.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks, I did not find these when searching, probably because I was only searching for "ebooks" and not more generally for "copyrighted material".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: My question was intended to clarify if I should flag those comments/posts, not if I should do something like that myself.